# Character from being automatically convert in the Instruments testing

Tags: objective-c, automation, instruments, ui-automation

I'm in the test using the instruments.
I'm trying to enter the string in the text box as follows.

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()["Empty list"].cells()["Server"].textFields()[0].tap();
target.frontMostApp().keyboard().typeString("https");
```

But, "https" is will end up with "http a".
The cause is predictive conversion Is there any measures?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by turning off the auto-collection.
Thanks!

[image]